# Align elements in the middle

Tags: html, css, alignment

I all, i've this part of code

HTML:

```
<div id="services"></div>
<div class="modular-row features small">
<div class="content-inner">
<h1>Für alle Ihre Werte</h1>
<div class="feature-items">
<div class="feature">
<a href=""><img style="" src="/sdstest/user/pages/01.home/_01.services/icon1.png" /></a>
                    <div class="feature-content icon-offset">
<h4>Rechenzentrum</h4>
                    </div>
</div>
           <div class="feature">
<a href=""><img style="" src="/sdstest/user/pages/01.home/_01.services/icon2.png" /></a>
                    <div class="feature-content icon-offset">
                                <h4>Kollaboration</h4>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature">
<a href=""><img style="" src="/sdstest/user/pages/01.home/_01.services/icon3.png" /></a>
                    <div class="feature-content icon-offset">
                                <h4>Archiv</h4>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature">
<a href=""><img style="" src="/sdstest/user/pages/01.home/_01.services/icon4.png" /></a>
                    <div class="feature-content icon-offset">
                                <h4>Wertsachen</h4>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.feature { margin-right: 2rem; }
```

What i need is
1: to center the class="feature" elements in the middle
2: have a bit of space between that elements (as is it now).

But this is result:

[image]

How can i solve it?

(Demo): https://jsfiddle.net/kf3u042k/

[image]

Comment: can u create a demo? / share all relevant code

Comment: provide jsfiddle. because some CSS are missing

Comment: here a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/kf3u042k/

Comment: @KarSho added the demo in the main post

Comment: So https://jsfiddle.net/kf3u042k/1/ this is your fiddle. Wt you want?

Comment: to alling the "feature" elemnts in the middle. As you can see from the screenshot 3 elements are centered and the 4th not. How can i solve it? @KarSho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the width and then put your side margin on auto. It would be something like this:

```
.feature{
    max-width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-left: x px;
}
```

for the space just ad a padding-left on your feature (cf code). Still if your width is not large enough it will go bad

Answer (score 2):

You can change css somthing like this

```
.modular .features .feature {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 24%;
}

.feature {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this code into your stylesheet. `.feature{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width:900px;
}`

Comment: I've tried, but now i have no space between the elements. See the new screenshot

Comment: try to increase max-width. This would solve probably.

Comment: and to provide space, just try padding:1em; on feature element.

Comment: Yes em should be better than px if you are working with proportions